# in ruby, is it possible to redefine the execution context of an added method?

Tags: ruby

For example

```
class Foo

  def bar
  end

end
```

In that code, bar would only be available within any instance of the class.

Is it possible to change the execution context of the method to the `Eigenclass`
without changing how the method itself is defined so that the method is now available as a singleton without ever needing to call `self.new`?

Preferably I would like to do it any of the code that doe this to code that is added in via a class that `Foo` could inherit from.

At the moment what I'm doing amounts to:

```
class Test

  def method_added method
    self.define_singleton_method method do 
      self.new.send method
    end
  end

end
```

and for what I need this doesn't work as I'm changing the execution context by calling `new`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out how to do it just now >_<.

Here's the code:

```
class Test
    def method_added method
        m = self.new.method(method) #get method object
        self.define_singleton_method(method) do #create method with same name within the singleton class 
             m.call  #call the block which will now run the code of the added method within the context of the Eigenclass/Singleton
        end
    end
end
```

So what it does is it grabs a method object form an instance and then calls that method as a block within the context of the class.

So the first code example becomes:

```
class Foo < Test

  def bar

  end

end
```

and the method `bar` can now be accessed as
`Foo.bar` rather then `Foo.new.bar` which means no instance creation; besides the time it does within method added, but that's fine as it's the only way to get the method object as far as I'm aware.

Which is why it's probably best to create an instance only the once when the class is inherited (within `def self.inherited`), store it within the class and then just access that instead of calling `self.new`.

Answer (score 0):

You  can simply do:

```
class Test
  def self.method_added method
    module_function method  
  end
end

class A < Test
  def foo
    :hello
  end
end

A.foo #=> :hello
```

Comment: yes, it just errors with `undefined method  'module_function'  for  Test:Class:`

Comment: @user3536548 - what ruby version do you use?

Comment: `ruby -v ` results in `2.1.3p242`